# Fast method to calc th Fourier transform

Tags: signal, frequency, energy, fourier

exist a fast method to calc the Fourier trasform (in both sense, t -> f and f->t)? When I use the table and the properties of the Fourier transform, sometime I have difficult to calc this...
Any help or suggestion are appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Difficulty = slow and fast = no difficulty so if you are having difficulty then that's probably then reason why. Do you know why you are having a difficulty?

Comment: @Andyaka honestly is an argument explained really bad in university... And I would solve this gap

Comment: Give an example of a difficult FT, and show how far you can go.

Comment: for example: $$\prod (\frac{2t}{T}) $$, $$\prod (2t)$$, $$\prod (\frac{t-2}{2})$$, $$2\Lambda(\frac{t-1}{2})$$.
I search a good method to calc every fourier transfor because this posted by me isn't so hard but I have some difficults

Answer (score 0):

See the "fast Fourier transform". It has been around for quite a while. 
Also Dina Katabi has an even faster version that can work in some circumstances: "MIT CSAIL Principal Investigators Dina Katabi and Piotr Indyk have developed a new algorithm that improves on the fast Fourier transform (FFT),"

Answer (score 0):

Depends whether you are talking about the Fourier transform or the discrete Fourier transform.
For the latter, there is an efficient algorithm, called FFT (fast Fourier transform). 
For the former, you usually have to use tables, the properties of the transform and your wits. In general, there is no short-cut.